# Javascript: Split a string into array matching parameters

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a string that has numbers and math operators (`+`,`x`,`-`, `/`) mixed in it

`'12+345x6/789'`

I need to convert it into an array seperated by those math operators.

`[12, +, 345, x, 6, /, 789]`

What is a simple way of doing this?

Comment: I looked into regex and String.prototype.split but I can't find a way to implement this easily in a 1 or  2 liner

Comment: How do you want to handle what is neither an operator nor a digit? My approach strips them.

Comment: @AluanHaddad hm I didn't think about that. The other solutions are either all digits or all nondigits....... but yours is all digits, operators, and everything else?

Comment: No my solution _discards_ anything that is not a digit or an op

Comment: By everything else I meant "discard everything else"

Comment: Yes, that's what it does except for whitespace between numbers, which it retains, keeping them together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splitting on consecutive [non-digit](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) chars `\D+` you get

```js
console.log ('12+345x6/789'.split (/\D+/))
// [ '12', '345', '6', '789' ]
```

If you add a [capture group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html), `(\D+)` you get the separator too

```js
console.log ('12+345x6/789'.split (/(\D+)/))
// [ "12", "+", "345", "x", "6", "/", "789" ]
```

If you want to support parsing decimals, change the regexp to `/([^0-9.]+)/` - Note, `\D` used above is equivalent to `[^0-9]`, so all we're doing here is adding `.` to the character class

```js
console.log ('12+3.4x5'.split (/([^0-9.]+)/))
// [ "12", "+", "3.4", "x", "5" ]
```

And a possible way to write the rest of your program

```js
const cont = x =>
  k => k (x)

const infix = f => x =>
  cont (f (x))

const apply = x => f =>
  cont (f (x))

const identity = x =>
  x

const empty =
  Symbol ()
  
const evaluate = ([ token = empty, ...rest], then = cont (identity)) => {
  if (token === empty) {
    return then
  }
  else {
    switch (token) {
      case "+":
        return evaluate (rest, then (infix (x => y => x + y)))
      case "x":
        return evaluate (rest, then (infix (x => y => x * y)))
      case "/":
        return evaluate (rest, then (infix (x => y => x / y >> 0)))
      default:
        return evaluate (rest, then (apply (Number (token))))
    }
  }
}

const parse = program =>
  program.split (/(\D+)/)
  
const exec = program =>
  evaluate (parse (program)) (console.log)

exec ('')             // 0
exec ('1')            // 1
exec ('1+2')          // 3
exec ('1+2+3')        // 6
exec ('1+2+3x4')      // 24
exec ('1+2+3x4/2')    // 12
exec ('12+345x6/789') // 2
```

Comment: 2nd solution doesn't have seperators in it can you double check

Comment: @Kagerjay wups, I added the `()` in the explanation, but not in the source code. I fixed the 2nd snippet :D

Comment: where exactly is the capture group on 2nd solution (aren't they normally `$1`,`$2`, etc)? Having trouble understanding this one

Comment: Okay I found its on MDN page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split. "If separator is a regular expression that contains capturing parentheses, then each time separator is matched, the results (including any undefined results) of the capturing parentheses are spliced into the output array. However, not all browsers support this capability."

Comment: @Kagerjay I included a way to write the rest of your program

Comment: By the way I noticed something wrong with this solution. If you used `12+345x` as the input the output becomes`[12,+,345,""]`

Comment: @Kagerjay there’s no error handling for invalid programs like the example you shared

Answer (score 2):

If you are unconcerned with whitespace, all you need is

```
'12+345x6/78-9'.match(/\d+|[\+-\/x]/g);
```

which splits the string into numbers and the `+`, `-`, `\`, and `x` tokens.

```js
'use strict';
const tokens = '12+345x6/78-9'.match(/\d+|[\+-\/x]/g);

console.log(tokens);
```

To handle whitespace, consider

```
'12+3 45 x6/78-9'.match(/\d|\d[\s\d]\d|[\+-\/x]/g);
```

which splits the string into numbers (optionally allowing whitespace as a digit separator within a single number) and `+`, `-`, `\`, and `x`.

```js
'use strict';
const tokens = '12+3 45 x6/78-9'.match(/\d+\s?\d+|\d+|[\+-\/x]/g);


console.log(tokens);
```

Comment: You forgot the `x`

Comment: could you put the original simple version you had too ? :)

Comment: @Kagerjay found a bug and fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

this is going to work

```js
console.log('12+345x6/789'.match(/\D+|\d+/g))
```

Comment: is this seperating by digits `\d+` and nondigits `\D+`

Comment: @Kagerjay,yes,you got it