# Regex Unexpected ^ and character match

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regular expression that tokenizes calculator input strings like `12+3.4x5` to `12`,`+`,`3.4`,`x`,`5`

The regular expression used is

`\d+\.?\d+|[\+-÷x]`

I get an unexpected match with `^` and letters.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post duplicates of your own question

Comment: I provided an edit to [my original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49546478/633183) that includes support for decimal numbers

Comment: I used shuntyard algorithm instead of eval

Comment: The minus sign (`-`) is a special character in a character class (`[]`). It needs to be escaped. `+` is Unicode `\u002B` and `÷` is unicode `\u00F7`, so `+-÷` is the range of **all** characters from `2B` to `F7`, which includes `^` (`\u005E`).

Answer (score 0):

Regex solution, although there's probably a cleaner way of writing this if someone could point it out?

`(\d+\.?\d+|\d+|(\+|-|÷|x))`

[image]

Comment: Why do you want it to match `|` characters?

Comment: I was trying to use it as a boolean OR operator but didn't do it correctly, I fixed it now